# Is it possible to require the original/actual implementation of a mocked Jest module from within the mocked module itself?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

My app is set up so that inside my Jest config, I have a module name mapping like so:

```
// jest.config.js
moduleNameMapper: {
  'utils': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/utilMock.js',
},
```

If, inside this mock, I wanted to pass through some of the original implementation, I should be able to do this, in theory:

```
// ./__mocks__/utilMock.js

const actualUtils = jest.requireActual('/utils');

module.exports = {
  actualUtils.funcA,
  actualUtils.funcB,
  funcC: jest.fn(),
  funcD: jest.fn(),
};
```

However, when I actually try to test this, `requireActual` doesn't give me back the original implementation, so all my tests break thinking `funcA` and `funcB` aren't functions.

Is this actually possible to do, or does the `utils` module just get mocked out regardless of what you do when it's set up globally via Jest config?

Comment: is you path correct? What if you change it to `jest.requireActual('../utils');`

Comment: Ah this didn't carry well over into the example, but I'm using absolute/full paths for all my imports, so they're definitely right, yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this isn't possible to do when you're using the module mapping, but it *will* work if you're using automocking. So, instead of specifying mock files in the `moduleNameMapper` of `jest.config.js`, make sure automocking is enabled and then have a file with the same name and path of the file you're trying to mock out under your `__mocks__` (or otherwise aliased) directory.

Anything you import/require there should be referencing the original implementation!